# Reduce the gap between Collapse icon and Labels in Treeviewer/TableViewer

Tags: eclipse-plugin

[image]

I have a treeviewer in my eclipse code. Is there a way to control the space between the collapseable icon and the resource icons, programmatically? Please, see the above image for reference

Comment: I think the only thing you can do is make sure the icons don't have any space at the left. There is no API to set the spacing.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I'll try to trim the white space then